# Change data in parent table from child table using stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write an app that is using 4 tables, one of which is dependent on the other 3. My goal is to be able to change data from the child table using a stored procedure in the parent tables, but the problem is that in the child table I only have foreign keys referencing the identity columns in the parent tables, and I don't know how to refer any other columns from the parent tables.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Pogon(
PogonID int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
NazivGoriva nvarchar (10) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE MarkeAutomobila(
MarkaID int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
NazivMarke nvarchar (50) NOT NULL,
Pogon int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Pogon (PogonID) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE Vlasnik(
VlasnikID int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Ime nvarchar (30) NOT NULL,
Prezime nvarchar (30) NOT NULL,
GodinaRodjenja int NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE Automobili(
AutomobilID int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
NazivMarke int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES MarkeAutomobila (MarkaID) NOT NULL,
VlasnikAutomobila int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Vlasnik (VlasnikID),
Pogon int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Pogon (PogonID) NOT NULL,
RegistracioniBroj nvarchar (12) NOT NULL)


CREATE PROC PromeniAutomobi
(
@AutomobilID
@Ime
@Prezime
@GodinaRodjenja
@NazivMarke
@NazivPogona
@RegistracioniBroj
)
AS
UPDATE Automobili
SET // I don't know what should i put here//
FROM Automobili AS a
INNER JOIN Vlasnik AS v
ON a.VlasnikAutomobila = v.VlasnikID
INNER JOIN MarkeAutomobila AS m
ON a.NazivMarke = m.MarkaID
INNER JOIN Pogon AS p
ON a.Pogon=p.PogonID
```

In the app I want to be able to add or change existing "Automobil" from one window using stored procedure, but also to change some items in e.g. "MarkeAutomobila"

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  It's not very clear what you are trying to do and what your problem is.  It would help if you could post the table definitions of all your tables  and what you've tried so far. Also, if you could post expected results that would help.

Comment: hope is more clear now.

Comment: You just need some `UPDATE` statements. If you've got the ID of the row in the parent table, then you can UPDATE any of the other fields in that row. What have you tried? It's still not entirely obvious why this is causing you a difficulty, unless you just don't know how to write an UPDATE statement correctly.

Comment: @ADyson I'm still learning SQL. I have edited my question. Problem is i don't know how to address parameters for procedure and connect them with right table.

Comment: you simply put the parameter name into the query in the place where otherwise you would write a specific value. e.g. as a generic example, something like `WHERE column1 = @parameter1`, or `SET column2 = @parameter2`.

Comment: P.S. I think you should study a simple tutorial to understand these kinds of basic concepts. For instance http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/ has a whole section dedicated to stored procedures, and even a specific page about parameters: http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-stored-procedure-parameters/